# standard format to describe opening schedules

Tags: serialization, date-format, csv

I am working on a project in which I have to model opening schedules (eg a swimming pool is opened from 10:30am to 5pm on Tuesday from january to May. I try to fit this data in a csv and I started using a homemade format (the swimming pool example would be `1/1-30/5|Tu:10+30-17`).

I am not really happy with that and I tried to look for a standard format to describe opening schedules. However I failed to find anything relevant. The closest I could find was [Repeating intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Repeating_intervals) but it isn't really what I want.

Is there any standard format to describe opening schedules?

Comment: who needs to read it?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Non technical people will fill the data. Then offline scripts will be used to generate json documents used in a web application.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need a decision tree of some kind. something like `(not holiday) and month between jan-may and day of week is Tuesday and hour between 10:30-17`

This is the closest to the natural language constraints the non technical users will have to input.

To input them I suggest using a proper gui that allows the user to select the various types. And a calender window to show the result.

Comment: Thanks! It is not standard, but I like your suggestion!